# Unknown method when attempting to post scores on facebook from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I'm using the following to post a score against the facebook scores API

```
- (IBAction)postScoreClicked:(id)sender 
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"score"];
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithMethodName:@"/563645402/scores" andParams:dict andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Posting a new score...");
}
```

However, overriding the `request didFailWithError` I can clearly see the following error being logged :

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x68982d0 {request_args=(
        {
        key = method;
        value = "/563645402/scores";
    },
        {
        key = sdk;
        value = ios;
    },
        {
        key = score;
        value = 1;
    },
        {
        key = "sdk_version";
        value = 2;
    },
        {
        key = format;
        value = json;
    },
        {
        key = "access_token";
        value = VALUE-REMOVED-FROM-POST;
    }
), error_msg=Unknown method, error_code=3}
```

According to the [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/) :

> You can post a score or a user by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   /USER_ID/scores with the app access_token as long as you have the
>   publish_actions permission

In my login controller, I've set the `publish_actions` permission like so :

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    @"user_games_activity", 
                                    @"friends_games_activity",
                                    @"publish_actions",
                                    nil];
            [[myDelegate facebook] authorize:permissions];
```

Not quite sure what I'm missing here, any ideas?

On the facebook app control center, my app is registered native/desktop, and categorised as a game

Comment: Are you using application's `access_token` and not one of the current user?